# difference between data in two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in a database in SQL server 2008, both tables have 20 column.At first the data was inserted in table A and later the same data was reentered in table B. Now I want to check what is the difference of data between the two tables and the difference output could be a number in percentage showing the data difference between two tables. Below I am sharing the pictures of my database. Some data is numerical and have data type as float and some is text and has datatype varchar. Below are some snaps of my database.
[image: 1st picture]

[image: 2nd picture]

Now I was wondering if there is any solution to my problem which is fast enough  so that I can calculate the difference among the two tables. Please note that the difference should be column by column.

Any tutorial which illustrates such problem any algorithm of c#. If there is any SQL query that solves my problem here without going on any other platform would be excellent.

Comment: Have you tried `EXCEPT` in sql query?

Comment: @HasanGholamali no I haven't tried except sql query? does that show difference among columns in a number?

Comment: What does your exact output look like?  There are a number of ways to do this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen wait I will upload a sample output picture.

Comment: @zainulabidin as it's document says `EXCEPT` returns distinct rows from the left input query that aren’t output by the right input query.

Comment: Your question is not clear.  At one point you say you want "a number".  At another, you want something done "column by column".  Those are different.  You also don't specify if there is a key identifying that two rows are (or should be) the same.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find out the percentage of non matching records of each table, then we may try using a full outer join:

```
SELECT
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN b.col1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) /
        COUNT(a.col1) AS pct_a_missing,
    100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN a.col1 IS NULL THEN 1 END) /
        COUNT(b.col1) AS pct_b_missing
FROM tableA a
FULL OUTER JOIN tableB b
    ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND
       a.col2 = b.col2    -- and all other columns
```

Follow the link below for a short demo showing that the above query logic works.

### Demo

We can also use the `EXCEPT` operator here.  For example, to find the percentage of rows in table A which don't match to anything in tableB, we can use this:

```
SELECT
    100.0 * (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM
    (SELECT * FROM tableA EXCEPT SELECT * FROM tableB) t) /
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tableA) AS pct_a_missing;
```

### Demo

Comment: I will have to write cases for 20 columns like this? Is there any loop or something

Comment: @zainulabidin Adapting my join logic to 20 columns should take you less than 5 minutes.  You could look into using `EXCEPT` as well, which might avoid this.

Comment: @zainulabidin I edited my answer to give you an option using `EXCEPT`.

Comment: @TimBeigeleisen ok  let me try it

Comment: It is giving me 36.8830 percent of data difference........I was wondering if  the except takes into account data difference like this:value1=0.5 and value2=0.9 then 0. is same in both values but 5 and 9 is difference...Is that the case?

Comment: I don't know what you are asking, but yes it looks like your conception of what it means for two records to be identical is skewed.  In both examples I gave, two records are only the same if _every_ value in _every_ column is the same.  If you needed other logic, then you really should have put it into your question.